# Temporary function or stored procedure in T-SQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

Is there any chance to create temporary stored procedure or function on MS SQL 2005? I would like to use this stored procedure only in my query so after execution it will be gone.

I have a query I would like to EXEC against some data. But for every table I will process this command, I need to change some parts of it. So I thought I would create temporary SP that would return for me a query from arguments I provide (like table name and so on) and than execute this query by EXEC.

And this stored procedure will be not useful for me later so I would like to have it temporary so that when I end executing my query - it will disappear.

Comment: Edited answer re your comment

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Re your edit - it sounds like you should be using sp_ExecuteSQL against a (parameterized) `nvarchar` that contains TSQL.

Search on sp_ExecuteSQL; a simple example:

```
DECLARE @SQL nvarchar(4000),
 @Table varchar(20) = 'ORDERS',
 @IDColumn varchar(20) = 'OrderID',
 @ID int = 10248

 SET @SQL = 'SELECT * FROM [' + @Table + '] WHERE ['
  + @IDColumn + '] = @Key'

  EXEC sp_executesql @SQL, N'@Key int', @ID
```

Note that table and column names must be concatenated into the query, but values (such as `@Key`) can be parameterized.

---

There is a temporary stored procedure - but it is per connection, not per sp.

However, you might want to look at Common Table Expressions - they may be what you are after (although you can only read from them once).

Maybe if you can clarify what you are trying to *do*?

Comment: Can you clarify the "temporary stored procedure" bit? Do you mean sp_prepare or sp_executesql?

Comment: I've added some more expl about what I try to acomplish. Hope it helps to understand my idea.

Answer (score 35):

This question is a bit old, but the other answers failed to provide the syntax for creating temporary procedures.  The syntax is the same as for temporary tables: #name for local temporary objects, ##name for global temporary objects.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE #uspMyTempProcedure AS
BEGIN
  print 'This is a temporary procedure'
END
```

This is described in the "Procedure Name" section of the official documentation. http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187926%28v=sql.90%29.aspx

I'm using this technique to deduplicate the code for my primitive T-SQL unit tests.  A real unit testing framework would be better, but this is better than nothing and "garbage collects" after itself.

Comment: And how about functions? In order to be able to use them in SELECT COLUMN expressions?

Answer (score -3):

Just use the SQL of the stored proc inside your query. No need to create a stored procedure inside the DB, it won't give you any advantage over a normal query inside your query.

Comment: but this does not allow for reuse of the stored proc code - which i see as a benefit to this approach.